# StreamWriter

Tags: c#

Привет HashCode. Скажите вот если записывать данные в файл, то надо обязательно написать

```
StreamWrite sw = new StreamWirter(...);
sw.WriteLine("бла бла бла");
**sw.Close()**
```

Так вот скажите, можно ли сделать так чтобы та запись которая УЖЕ была в файлы не удалялась. А та что записалась, просто например на следующей строке записывалась.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Открывайте поток в режиме [`FileMode.Append`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filemode.aspx):

```
    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.Write("some text");
    }
```

Также рекомендуется оборачивать использование `IDisposable`-объектов в блок `using`.

Comment: А что за 

    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append))
Они же в самом начале программы только

Comment: `using` используется 1. для доступа к элементам, которые содержатся в заданном пространстве имён по неполному имени; 2. создания алиаса для заданного типа; 3. создания блока с гарантированным вызовом `Dispose()` у `IDisposable` объектов (это и есть данный случай).

Рекомендую почитать о языке поподробнее.

Answer (score 2):

Или так:

```
string appendText = "This is extra text";
File.AppendAllText(pathToFile, appendText);
```

> Opens a file, appends the specified
> string to the file, and then closes
> the file. If the file does not exist,
> this method creates a file, writes the
> specified string to the file, then
> closes the file.